# Activiti bypass activiti rest and call directly to activiti core error

Tags: spring-data-jpa, workflow, alfresco, activiti, bpmn

Hi I have an activiti rest project which will call the **repository/process-defination** to get the all the definitions
from an activiti, where activiti rest api is like this-

```
@GetMapping(value = "/repository/process-definitions", produces = "application/json")
    public DataResponse getProcessDefinitions @RequestParam Map<String, String> allRequestParams, HttpServletRequest request) {
```

Now instead of calling the activiti rest I need  to directly call the activiti core and need to get the same result-
I try to implement like this but not able to get the data, what i need to do to get the exact data like activiti rest from above?

```
    public class MyClass{
    @Autowired
    private ProcessEngine processEngine;
    public List<ProcessDefination> getDef(Map<String, String> allRequestParams){
    RepositoryService rs = processEngine.getRepositoryService();
    return rs.createProcessDefinationQuery().list();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the source code? With which version of Activiti are you working with? I think the easiest way would be cloning the method's source code (which for Activiti 6 is [here](https://github.com/Activiti/Activiti/blob/6.x/modules/activiti-rest/src/main/java/org/activiti/rest/service/api/repository/ProcessDefinitionCollectionResource.java)).